# Almost periodic functions in Tao's ergodic proof of Szemerédi's theorem 

Tags: ergodic-theory, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, additive-combinatorics

Do we say that a function $f$ is *uniformly almost periodic* in the aforementioned proof if $f$ is bounded (in the sense that $||f||_{L^\infty}\leq 1$) and that there exists a natural number $d>0$ such that $f\in UAP^d$?

*Edit*: the proof in question appears in Tao's paper "A quantitative ergodic theory proof of Szemerédi's theorem".

Comment: I'm not really sure what this question wants.  From a quick read of the paper (available here: http://www.combinatorics.org/Volume_13/PDF/v13i1r99.pdf) the answer is "yes, but I don't see why we need $\|f\|_{L^\infty}\leq 1$".

Comment: The question wants the definition of uniformly almost periodic functions in the *paper* and not in the infinitary ergodic theory setting.

Comment: I think uniform almost periodicity here mean being an element of $UAP^d$.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment above, a uniform almost periodic function (of order $d$) is an element of $UAP^d$ for some $d$. The bound $||f||_{L^\infty}\leq1$ is unnecessary.

Comment: +1, as I agree (and I said this in my comment above as well!)

Answer (score -1):

I think it means the continuous functions on the Bohr compactification of the reals.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_periodic_function#Uniform_or_Bohr_or_Bochner_almost_periodic_functions

Comment: Well, the setting in Tao's proof is finitary, in the sense that the function $f$ above is defined on a finite cyclic group $Z_N$. Thus, continuous functions on the Bohr compactification of the reals might not be the answer.